# how to create a tuple of tuples with variables being assigned inside python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a lot of variables on tuples formats, and i need to put them all in another tuple or a list.

```
NAME = (1, "JOHN")
AGE = (2, 36)
COUNTRY = (3, "USA")
```

And i needed something that i could acess the two values of them(like 1, "JOHN" for the NAME) by the variable name and get the value.
Something that would look like this:

```
LIST = [ NAME = (1, "JOHN"),  AGE = (2, 36), COUNTRY = (3, "USA")]
```

If someone knows a format that i could acess the two values of the variable, by puting something like LIST.NAME[1] to acess "JOHN".

Comment: Neither lists nor tuples support named entries. You might be looking for a dict.

Comment: There are [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), though

Answer (score 0):

As the comment mentions, you probably want a dictionary. Something like...

```
my_dict ={'name': (1, 'john'), 'age': (2, 36), 'origin': (3, 'usa')}
```

You can then access the name tuple with `my_dict['name']`